# Wildfly 10, standalone, classpath

Tags: spring, wildfly

Springboot приложение не видит некоторые файлы-ресурсы, когда пытаюсь деплоить на wildfly 10 в standalone режиме.

Когда же запускаю через `gradle run` (автоматически запускается tomcat),  `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` содержит путь

```
*****/build/classes/main
```

По этому пути лежат конг. файлы и файлы маппинга, т.е. в этом режиме все работает (путь),

Когда пытаюсь сделать deploy на wildfly получаю только

```
/home/***/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar
```

Как в wildfly настроить путь в проекте по умолчанию к `*****/build/classes/main?`
Спасибо.

Comment: wildfly-9.0.1.Final как бы совсем не 10. Вы уверены, что разворачивает в 10-ую версию? И с какого перепугу wildfly может понадобится classpath `*****/build/classes/main`? Если приложение развёртывается  правильно, то не нужен никакой classpath.

Comment: прошу прощения, 9 версия, приложение разворачивается правильно, но в момент выполнения происходит ошибка, связанная с тем, что приложение не видит файл маппинга, в ресурсах

Comment: Эти файлы упаковываются в готовое приложение? Убедитесь, что они именно там, где их ожидает увидеть springboot. Или Вы сами их пытаетесь загрузить?

Comment: да, они упаковываются в приложение, и при запуске таким образом: 'java -jar examplename.war' все нормально, 
при запуске через 'gradle run' были проблемы, но это было исправлено, 'sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir' в build.gradle